# How to set hidden attributes to an Controller method in Laravel5.0?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to hide some data which selected from database but reinitialize from some method in Controller not defined in its Models.

```
function ddd(){
        return Client::select($this->_client)->with([
            'Contact'=>function($s){
                //$this->setHidden('use_id');
                //$s->setHidden('use_id');
                $s->select($this->_contact);
            },
            'Employer'=>function($s){$s->select($this->_employers);},
        ])->get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You requirement is not very clear. However. I am assuming that you have 3 models Client hasOne Contact and belongsTo Employer.

In order to hide the `use_id` property of the Client model you can define a hidden property in your model

```
class Client extends Model
{
    //will hide the `use_id` from the model's array and json representation.
    protected $hidden = ['use_id'];  

    //Relations
    /**
     * Get the Contact which the given Client has.
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     * will return a App\Contact model
     */
    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Contact');
    }

    /**
     * Get the Employee to which the given Client belongs.
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     * will return a App\Employer model
     */
    public function employer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employer');
    }
}
```

Then in probably your ClientsController in some action ddd

```
public function ddd()
{
    return Client::with('contact')->with('employer')->get();
}
```

Comment: That is OK to declare the hidden properties for each models But i want to declare it inside of my function or manual declaration but I still can not find this solution

Comment: Okay as I understand you want to return some restricted fields for some request while for some other request you want to return all fields. In that case you can use raw sql queries with query builder and query using select statement wherein you can specify the restricted columns within a controller from where you want to return only restricted columns.